# how to get duplicate rows of a single column including other columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The structure of the table and data is as follows:

```
CityID    cityname  CountryID

A1         abc        IN
A2         bcd        IN
A2         cde        US
A2         def        UK
A3         efg        SL
A4         fgh        SL
A4         ghi        NZ
```

Here the `CityIDs` are duplicates and the output should be:

```
  CityID    cityname  CountryID

    A2         bcd        IN
    A2         cde        US
    A2         def        UK
    A4         fgh        SL
    A4         ghi        NZ
```

I am able to only find the count of duplicate id's using the query below:

```
SELECT CityID,COUNT(CityID) IDcount 
FROM tbl_City 
GROUP BY CityID 
HAVING (COUNT(CityID) >1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following query:-

```
SELECT CityID, cityname, CountryID
FROM tab
WHERE CityID IN (SELECT CityID FROM tab
                 GROUP BY CityID
                 HAVING COUNT(CityID) > 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using  [OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause:

```
DECLARE @tbl_city TABLE
(
     [CityID] CHAR(2)
    ,[CityName] VARCHAR(12)
    ,[CountryID] CHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl_city
VALUES ('A1', 'abc', 'IN')
    ,('A2', 'bcd', 'IN')
    ,('A2', 'cde', 'US')
    ,('A2', 'def', 'UK')
    ,('A3', 'efg', 'SL')
    ,('A4', 'fgh', 'SL')
    ,('A4', 'ghi', 'NZ')


;WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT CityID
          ,cityname
          ,CountryID
          ,COUNT(CityID) OVER(PARTITION BY CityID) IDcount 
    FROM @tbl_city 
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE IDcount > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH DuplicatesCTE AS
(
    SELECT   CityID
    FROM     Cities 
    GROUP BY CityID
    HAVING COUNT(CityID)>1
)
SELECT C.*
FROM   Cities C
       JOIN DuplicatesCTE D
           ON C.CityID = D.CityID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below query

```
select CityID,  cityname  CountryID, 
(SELECT count(CityID) FROM tbl_City in_City where in_City.CityID = CityID) AS  IDcount 
FROM tbl_City
```